# How to run custom network code in another thread in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cocos2d-x

How to run custom network code in another thread in cocos2d-x scene? I'm making turn-based multiplayer game on cocos2d-x and SDL_Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::thread` to create and detach second thread:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread thread_name([]()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
            std::cout << "Hello from other thread" << std::endl;
        }
    });
    thread_name.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(11));
    return 0;
}
```

Use `cocos2d::Scheduler` to schedule actions from that thread:

```
cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->schedule([](float)
{
    std::cout << "We can operate cocos-related things here" << std::endl;
}, this, 0.0f, 1, 0, false, "name");
```